# Comparing estimated distributions

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Consider the following: I have samples from two groups, and I want to answer the question are the BMIs for the two samples (say men and women) drawn from the same distribution? I do not want to compare the raw data, because I would like to control for any systematic differences (e.g., in ethnicity, health, SES, etc.) that may affect BMI. In other words, I would like to know if, *all else equal*, men and women have the same distribution of BMIs.

So I could estimate BMI = alpha + beta*vector_of_controls + error for the two samples. That is:

$$BMI = \alpha + \beta_{j} X_{j} + \varepsilon$$

At this point, should I compare (with a K-S test) the predicted values from the two regressions, or the error terms (i.e., the residuals)?

Comment: in the regression modell you would introduce a persons sex as a dummy variable. if the corresponding coefficient is significant different from 0, then the conditional means are different for the two groups. this would already imply that also the conditional distributions are different (which seems to be enough for you?!).